# Prove a function is Borel set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be any function (not necessarily measurable). Prove
that the set of points $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $F(y) \leq F(x) \leq F(z)$
for all $y \leq x$ and $z \geq x$ is Borel set.

I know that this is what a borel set is:

"The intersection of all the σ-algebras of subsets of R that contain the open sets is a σ-algebra called the Borel σ-algebra; members of this collection are called Borel sets."

So, would simply showing that F is open work?

Answer (score 2):

That would work . . . if $F$ were open (it's not). Indeed, *no* function is open (when identified with its graph) - this is a good exercise. (Note that there's a separate notion of a function being an open map, which is to say that it sends open sets to open sets.) Moreover, the $F$ in this question need not even be measurable, so it(s graph) need not even be Borel at all.

The main point, though, is that you're trying to prove the wrong thing: the problem doesn't ask you to show that $F$ is Borel, it asks you to show that the set of $x$ such that [stuff] is Borel. So think about it: is there anything you can say, topologically, about the set of $x$ with the property that the problem talks about?

HINT: Suppose $x_i$ are points with the property in the problem, and $x_i\rightarrow x$. What can you say about $x$? What does this imply about the set you care about?

Comment: Oh, right, it's the set of $x$ that I want to prove is Borel. Good point. It seems like this set $x$ is a diagonally-tilted/increasing plane in a 3D coordinate system.  (I hope I described in words accurately what's in my head).  So, if those points all converge to some $x$, then...hmm, I'm not sure where to go next...the resulting set would be a line?

Comment: @PBJ Try figuring out whether $x$ is in your set or not . . .